# Docker Windows build fails with error: "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: windows, docker, docker-for-windows

I tried to create a directory junction on Docker Windows to create 8.3 . But it failed with the error message below.

```
D:\data\docker\sample>docker build -t sample .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.272GB
Step 1/4 : FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
 ---> 2cddde20d95d
Step 2/4 : RUN fsutil.exe behavior set disable8dot3 0
 ---> Running in ec6e7cc09ec6
The registry state is now: 0 (Enable 8dot3 name creation on all volumes).
 ---> 53805bc21858
Removing intermediate container ec6e7cc09ec6
Step 3/4 : RUN mklink /J "C:\PROGRA~1" "C:\Program Files"
 ---> Running in 2116f2070e6a
Junction created for C:\PROGRA~1 <<===>> C:\Program Files
re-exec error: exit status 1: output: time="2017-10-03T16:15:54+09:00" level=error msg="hcsshim::ImportLayer failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3) layerId=\\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\5234d5f7cd7c2669db1818d9227a4be2822eeb72fc30071a495de78cd578b9f3 flavour=1 folder=C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hcs088640839"
hcsshim::ImportLayer failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3) layerId=\\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\5234d5f7cd7c2669db1818d9227a4be2822eeb72fc30071a495de78cd578b9f3 flavour=1 folder=C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\hcs088640839
```

The Dockerfile was below:

```
FROM microsoft/windowsservercore
RUN fsutil.exe behavior set disable8dot3 0
RUN mklink /J "C:\PROGRA~1" "C:\Program Files"
CMD [ "powershell" ]
```

How can I create a directory juction on Docker Windows?

Answer (score 28):

I'm guessing your issue is actually not related to creating a directory junction (note that your build did complete that step), but is related to exceeding the base size of docker containers (I see you're pulling from windowsservercore, which is about 10GB, and [web browsing](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/32408) tells me the default container base size is 10GB).

Try changing the size to 20GB in the docker daemon config by adding this json:

```
"storage-opts": [
  "size=20G"
]
```

[image: daemon config]

I was experiencing the same error message, tried all manner of troubleshooting, and resolved it with that daemon setting.

Comment: This saved me. I've had a build failing for a few days now and don't know why I didn't stumble across this sooner. Finally succeeded. Where I could see this error happening for any number of reasons, I bet this will be a large number of cases. This should probably be marked as the answer seeing as OP never came back.

Answer (score 1):

For Docker Enterprise this can be configured here C:\ProgramData\docker\config\daemon.json

```
"storage-opts":["size=20G"]
```

If this file does not exist created it

[Link here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/manage-docker/configure-docker-daemon)

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to resolve this with other methods; what worked for me was deleting and re-pulling the base image.  So, it is apparently possible to get this error from a corrupt image.

(For reference, my error was `The system cannot find the path specified. (0x2)` not `The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3)`.)

Answer (score 0):

check if the project is Running or not ! if it is running finish it. then check the command again

Answer (score 0):

It seems that junctions and and hardlinks are not supported by docker for windows.

I had similar problem trying to create a container with Cygwin inside. Cygwing uses hardlinks a lot. It all went wwll until Docker tried to commit an image and it failed with "hcsshim::ImportLayer - cannot find the path" error. When I got rid of the hardlinks in the container I was able to commit the image without problems.