# Building ASP.NET Core API Docker Image failed in windows

Tags: asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I am new in Docker world. I create a simple ASP.NET Core API. I try to build a Docker image but I won't build.

This is my docker file.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1803 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-sdk-nanoserver-1803 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["FirstDemo/FirstDemo.csproj", "FirstDemo/"]
RUN dotnet restore "FirstDemo/FirstDemo.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/FirstDemo"
RUN dotnet build "FirstDemo.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "FirstDemo.csproj" -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "FirstDemo.dll"]
```

and here is my error

```
Step 1/17 : FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1803 AS base
2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1803: Pulling from microsoft/dotnet
e46172273a4e: Pull complete
68aae72b77f3: Pull complete
02db7ef764ae: Pull complete
b85c87d0746a: Pull complete
8ded5310ea16: Pull complete
50f3c06b2324: Pull complete
57b0e03264f9: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:7b0c816859dca7eeab5ae92fea96090fb37fc966622649db0567f0c752552d4a
Status: Downloaded newer image for microsoft/dotnet:2.2-aspnetcore-runtime-nanoserver-1803
 ---> 422d1790b708
Step 2/17 : WORKDIR /app
 ---> Running in 8ae8be6cb8c0
**re-exec error: exit status 1: output: time="2019-02-19T23:15:48-05:00" level=error msg="hcsshim::ImportLayer failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3) path=\\\\?\\C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\windowsfilter\\*****  folder=C:\\ProgramData\\Docker\\tmp\\hcs815654479"
hcsshim::ImportLayer failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3) path=\\?\C:\ProgramData\Docker\windowsfilter\****** folder=C:\ProgramData\Docker\tmp\hcs815654479**
```

I also find this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46539165/docker-windows-build-fails-with-error-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specifie) but it does not help me. Please advice me.

Answer (score 0):

For those who might have the same issue.

the problem was our security application ( CHECKPOINT- ENDPOINT Security)

it blocks the access of Docker to file system. for now, we remove it, then everything is going well.