# Error installing cygwin in docker container: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3) error=hcsshim::ImportLayer - failed failed in Win32

Tags: docker, dockerfile, cygwin, docker-for-windows, windows-server-2019

I have a simple Dockerfile:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809

# Install chocolatey
RUN powershell.exe Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))

# Install cygwin
RUN choco install -y cygwin --version 3.1.2
RUN refreshenv

CMD [ "powershell" ]
```

The result is

```
PS C:\vagrant\delme> docker build . -t localhost/async_windows_service
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/5 : FROM mcr.microsoft.com/windows:1809
 ---> 2de0138f1799
Step 2/5 : RUN powershell.exe Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7ee59b0c4334
Step 3/5 : RUN choco install -y cygwin --version 3.1.2
 ---> Running in e6c3d1130a4e
Chocolatey v0.10.15
Installing the following packages:
cygwin
By installing you accept licenses for the packages.
Progress: Downloading chocolatey-core.extension 1.3.5.1... 100%
Progress: Downloading Cygwin 3.1.2... 100%

chocolatey-core.extension v1.3.5.1 [Approved]
chocolatey-core.extension package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
 Installed/updated chocolatey-core extensions.
 The install of chocolatey-core.extension was successful.
  Software installed to 'C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\extensions\chocolatey-core'

Cygwin v3.1.2 [Approved]
cygwin package files install completed. Performing other installation steps.
Download site: http://mirrors.kernel.org/sourceware/cygwin/
Installing 64-bit Cygwin...
Cygwin has been installed.
Added C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin\Cygwin.exe shim pointed to 'c:\tools\cygwin\cygwin.bat'.
Copying cygwin package manager (setup) to C:\tools\cygwin
Environment Vars (like PATH) have changed. Close/reopen your shell to
 see the changes (or in powershell/cmd.exe just type `refreshenv`).
 ShimGen has successfully created a shim for setup-x86.exe
 The install of cygwin was successful.
  Software installed to 'C:\tools\cygwin'

Chocolatey installed 2/2 packages.
 See the log for details (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\logs\chocolatey.log).
re-exec error: exit status 1: output: time="2020-06-02T22:03:52+02:00" level=error msg="hcsshim::ImportLayer - failed failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3)" error="hcsshim::ImportLayer - failed failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3)" importFolderPath="C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\tmp\\hcs292836507" path="\\\\?\\C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\eeae1d5f886b0b035f4466cf124056f7c1924283548cd960e0024a33d1219984"
hcsshim::ImportLayer - failed failed in Win32: The system cannot find the path specified. (0x3)
```

I tried different version of cygwin, also modified the storage size, as suggested e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46539165/docker-windows-build-fails-with-error-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specifie).

It is strange. The installation seems to go fine but docker cannot find the file (a layer I suppose) with `path="\\\\?\\C:\\ProgramData\\docker\\windowsfilter\\eeae1d5f886b0b035f4466cf124056f7c1924283548cd960e0024a33d1219984"`

And indeed, in my `C:\ProgramData\docker\windowsfilter` directory, there is no folder starting with eeae1d...

Note that only cygwin is causing problems. I can install all kinds of other software.

Comment: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/41058

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Docker Windows build fails with error: "The system cannot find the path specified"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46539165/docker-windows-build-fails-with-error-the-system-cannot-find-the-path-specifie)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that it is hardlinks which Cygwin uses a lot are not handled correctly by Docker. And in particular when Docker tries to commit an image it fails with "hcsshim::ImportLayer - cannot find the path" error.

I run in the same problem recently and after I got rid of the hardlinks in Cygwin installation I was able to commit the image without problems.

To get rid of the hardlinks I have zipped and unzipped Cygwin folder.

Comment: Hi Dmytro, after running "RUN choco install -y cygwin --version 3.1.2", which commands do you mean saying of zipping and unzipping Cygwin folder?

Comment: I have actually done zip/unzip thingy on the host instead of container and than copied the version of cygwin folder without hardlinks to the container.